# Using developer tools to troubleshoot web issues - Warnings button does nothing?

Tags: asp.net, browser, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to troubleshoot an issue and the warnings button doesn't appear to be doing anything. When I start my app in Chrome, and hit F12, the dev tools window comes up with 87 warnings:

[image]

When I hit that warnings button, the console shows, but I don't see any warnings:

[image]

In fact, if I click the button to show only warnings, everything in the console goes away:

[image]

What are these warnings? How can I find them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably filtering out your CSS warnings.  They're filtered by default.

Click the **filter** and check:

[image]